# Distributing resources to consumers

Tags: graph-theory

Set 1 (left column) has y rows. Set 2 (top row) has x columns. y > x.

The rules of the distribution are:

- each column must have 5 `x`'s assigned
- in the right most column of the table below, there must not be more than 2 numbers in the set, that also appear in another set. For example `1,2,5` and `1,2,4` are fine but not `1,2,5` and `1,2,5`. Another example, `1,2,3,4,5` and `1,2,6,7,8` are fine, but not `1,2,3,4,5` and `1,2,3,6,7`.

What is the name for solving this? Is there a formula?

Here is an example solution with 10 rows as the input and the output then is 6 columns, and additionally, the explanation for that is here:

[image]